# Почему некоторые не делают проверку на капчу?

Tags: безопасность, веб-программирование, captcha, спам

Я заметил, что на многих сайтах, причём действительно крутых сайтах, не делают проверку капчи при отправки формы для связи на странице «Контакты».

Почему они отказались от капчи?

Comment: возможно, потому, что на спам / не спам они проверяют уже на сервере, каким-нибудь [Akismet](https://akismet.com/)'ом.

Comment: @Sergiks Что Вы имеете  в  виду? Обьясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Sergiks Так а почему на капчу не проверить? Что мешает? Это-же тоже хорошо, проверять на качпу. Тоже полезно.

Comment: Многие пользователи, и я в их числе, ненавидят заполнять капчу. Меньше действий – больше вероятность, что напишут.

Comment: `Что Вы имеете в виду`... то и имеется в виду. Запрос принимается от всех. А фильтрация происходит другим средством. Например вы позволяете в свой клуб входить всем, но, тем, кто не в вашем списке - стреляют в голову и уносят тело прочь...... А на каптчи многие жалуются, что невнятная,  ничего не разобрать, не проходит и прочее. Да и есть сервисы по подбору. Так что какой смысл слушать бесконечное нытье юзеров, а также в любом случае получать какой-то спам не взирая на каптчу? Проще на стороне уже применить средство фильтра и не мучиться

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Спасасибо. Да я даже не знаю. Это-же потенциальная дырка для досс атак.

Comment: @gilo1212 ну как бэ банально ограничить количество отправок с ip/id/email/адреса по времени не судьба?) Самый примитивный уровень защиты

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский ограничить через БД? Или через настройки web-сервера?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А если ip  не определяется.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский или на фаерволе?

Comment: @gilo1212: Запрос всё равно приходит с какого-то IP. Настоящий IP спрятан за файрволом — заблокирован будет файрвол, делов-то. Кому нужен настоящий IP вида 192.168.0.1?

Comment: По новым веяниям моды капча считается плохим тоном. Где-то наталкивался на статью с разбором этого явления, но уже не вспомню.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что капча сломалась. Ну или просто пользователь хочет написать "не могу разобрать вашу капчу". Как об этом сообщить, если на форме обратной связи используется та же самая капча?

Засыпать спамом админа сайта? А смысл?

Что касается dos-атак, то можно же и просто неверной капчой сервер засыпать.